# Split my file into 128 bytes using c++

Tags: c++, file

I am new to C++, and I need to make a program to read a file and divide it into blocks of 214 bytes. In Java, I used `readAllBytes()` like this:

```java
byte[] data= Files.readAllBytes(path);
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 215) {
    byte[] data1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, i, i + 214);
}
```

Now, in C++, I read the file into a buffer, but I dont have a clue how to divide the buffer into blocks of 214 bytes:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    FILE *fileptr;
    char *buffer;
    long filelen;

    fileptr = fopen("test.txt", "rb");  
    fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);        
    filelen = ftell(fileptr);         
    rewind(fileptr);                   
    buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen + 1) * sizeof(char)); 
    fread(buffer, filelen, 1, fileptr); 
    cout << buffer;

    fclose(fileptr); 
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me make this program, please?

Comment: Why not make a buffer `214` bytes long and try to read in a whole buffer each time?

Comment: You don't need to divide the buffer. Just take the data out of the buffer as you want/need it. Leave the buffer alone.

Comment: if you are using C++, please do not use `FILE`, raw pointers and `malloc`s. Use `std::fstream` and  `std::string` instead of C-style strings (`char *buffer`). It will save you a lot of headaches

Comment: 128 or 214? Make up your mind?

Answer (score 1):

After closing file:

```
char buff128[128];
long done = 0;
while (done < filelen)
{
    long available = min(128, filelen - done);
    memcpy(buffer + done, buff128, available);
    done += available;
    // Do whatever with buff128
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by min??

Comment: There can be lass than 128 bytes remained in buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a buffer the size of the chunks you want and try to read a full buffer each time, like this:

```
std::ifstream ifs("test.txt", std::ios::binary);

char buf[214];

while(ifs.read(buf, sizeof(buf)) || ifs.gcount())
{
    // use what was read in.

    // gcount() is the number of bytes actually read
    std::string chunk(buf, ifs.gcount());

    std::cout << chunk << '\n';
}
```

Bear in mind that the final buffer may well have less that `214` characters in it.

Comment: Can the functions be guaranteed to be executed in the order you specified in the `while` loop?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Which functions?

Comment: The `ifs.read()` and the `ifs.gcount()`.  My understanding is that functions could be executed in any order, but their results must be compared in the order given.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Not with `||` it has *short circuit* logic meaning the right hand side won't even be called unless the left hand side evaluates false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using buffer reads of 214:

```
static const size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 214U;
char buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
std::ifstream input("test.txt", std::ios::binary)
while (input.read(&buffer[0], BLOCK_SIZE))
{
  const size_t characters_read = input.gcount();
  Process_Buffer(buffer, characters_read);
}
```

The above examples uses the block reading capability by using the `read` method.

The array is declared before the input so that there is only one allocation.

The array can be passed to a function for processing.